# using scrapy to scrape asp.net website with javascript buttons and ajax requests

Tags: python, postback, web-scraping, scrapy

I'd been trying to scrape some date from as asp.net website, the start page should be the following one:
http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON

First, I want to display 50 item per page (from the select element)
Second, I want to paginate through pages.

I tried the following code for 50 items per page, but didn't work:

```
start_urls = ["http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON"]    
def parse(self, response):
        requests = []
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        # Check if there's more than 1 page         
        if len(hxs.select('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ItemListPlaceHolder_lbl_PageSize"]/text()').extract()) > 0:
            # Get last page number
            last_page = hxs.select('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ItemListPlaceHolder_lbl_PageSize"]/text()').extract()[0]
            i = 1

            # preparing requests for each page
            while i < (int(last_page) / 5)  + 1:
                requests.append(Request("http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON", callback=self.parse_product))
                i +=1 

            # posting form date (50 items and next page button)
            requests.append(FormRequest.from_response(
                    response,
                    formdata={'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$pagesddl':'50',
                              '__EVENTTARGET':'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$pager1$ctl00$ctl01'},
                    callback=self.parse_product,
                    dont_click=True
                )
            )

            for request in requests:
                yield request
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this here is an exact solution..

in parse method selecting 50 products per page

in page_rs_50 handled pagination

```
start_urls = ['http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON']
pro_urls = [] # all product Urls

def parse(self, response): # select 50 products on each page
    yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
        formdata={'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$pagesddl': '50',
                  'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$sortddl': 'Price(ASC)'},
        meta={'curr': 1, 'total': 0, 'flag': True},
        dont_click=True,
        callback=self.page_rs_50)

def page_rs_50(self, response): # paginate the pages
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    curr = int(response.request.meta['curr'])
    total = int(response.request.meta['total'])
    flag = response.request.meta['flag']
    self.pro_urls.extend(hxs.select(
        "//td[@class='name']//a[contains(@id,'ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ItemListPlaceHolder_itemslv_ctrl')]/@href"
    ).extract())
    if flag:
        total = hxs.select(
            "//span[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ItemListPlaceHolder_lbl_pagesizeBtm']/text()").re('\d+')[0]
    if curr < total:
        curr += 1
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$pagesddl': '50',
                      'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$sortddl': 'Price(ASC)',
                      'ctl00$ctl00$ScriptManager1': 'ctl00$ctl00$ScriptManager1|ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$pager1$ctl00$ctl01'
                , '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$pager1$ctl00$ctl01',
                      'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ItemListPlaceHolder$hfVSFileName': hxs.select(
                          ".//input[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ItemListPlaceHolder_hfVSFileName']/@value").extract()[
                                                                                          0]},
            meta={'curr': curr, 'total': total, 'flag': False},
            dont_click=True,
            callback=self.page_rs_50
        )
    else:
        for pro in self.pro_urls:
            yield Request("http://www.e3050.com/%s" % pro,
                callback=self.parse_product)


def parse_product(self, response):
    pass
    #TODO Implementation Required For Parsing
```

Comment: LOL, I pay you on freelancing website to publish my code publicly :) !!

Comment: @MahmoudM.Abdel-Fattah if i read out your question before geting job , i am sure i will help you out at some level without any payment :), we didn't sign any NDA thats why i posted it here as well so that next time some one has not to pay any bucks for this question on freelancing :)

Answer (score 1):

I did not extensively research your code, but i see something strange:

```
        # Get last page number
        last_page = hxs.select('//span[@id="ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ItemListPlaceHolder_lbl_PageSize"]/text()').extract()[0]
        i = 1

        # preparing requests for each page
        while i < (int(last_page) / 5)  + 1:
            requests.append(Request("http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON", callback=self.parse_product))
            i +=1
```

First, instead of these manipulations with `i`, you can do:

```
        for i in xrange(1, last_page // 5 + 1):
```

Then you do:

```
            requests.append(Request("http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON", callback=self.parse_product))
```

Are you creating many requests to the same URL?

Comment: Yes, I'm creating many POST requests to the same URL to change items count per page and paginate.

Comment: `Request("http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON", callback=self.parse_product)` but in the url there is no counter. `i` is not used.

Comment: I changed it to : `requests.append(Request("http://www.e3050.com/Items.aspx?cat=SON&page=%s" % i, callback=self.parse_product))`

But the problem that it makes only 1st request as POST and the rest requests as GET

Comment: Then make `FormRequest`s instead of `Request`s

Comment: I hired freelancer to make it. Here's the final code http://pastebin.com/aEF6bSWK , just replace SitName with (e 3 0 5 0 . c o m) with no spaces

Comment: I'm facing similar issue but I have a search form where i first need to click on "find" button in order to get all results.

you solution did not work for me.
any ideas?